# Is there an efficient way to do this excel function

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

In excel I wanted to differentiate the starting time of a trip into 4 'times of day' (Morning, afternoon, evening, Night)

I made this script, the start_time column consists of time (hh:mm:ss)

```
=IF(
    AND([@[start_time]] >= TIME(20,0,0),
        [@[start_time]] <= TIME(23,59,59)
    ),
    "Night",
    IF(
        AND([@[start_time]] >= TIME(0,0,0), 
            [@[start_time]] < TIME(6,0,0)
        ),
        "Night",
        IF(
            AND([@[start_time]] >= TIME(6,0,0), 
                [@[start_time]] < TIME(12,0,0)
            ),
            "Morning",
            IF(
                AND([@[start_time]] >= TIME(12,0,0), 
                    [@[start_time]] < TIME(16,0,0)
                ),
                "Afternoon", 
                "Evening"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I was wondering if there is any way to improve this function or make it more easy
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a vlookup() and a table.

Comment: I would suggest avoiding `VLOOKUP`. `INDEX`/`MATCH` is better in every way. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can significantly simplify your `IF` statement by removing the `AND`s:

```
=IF([@[Start Time]]-ROUNDDOWN([@[Start Time]],0) < TIME(6,0,0), "Night",
  IF([@[Start Time]]-ROUNDDOWN([@[Start Time]],0) < TIME(12,0,0), "Morning",
    IF([@[Start Time]]-ROUNDDOWN([@[Start Time]],0) < TIME(16,0,0), "Afternoon",
      IF([@[Start Time]]-ROUNDDOWN([@[Start Time]],0) < TIME(20,0,0), "Evening", "Night")
    )
  )
```

The `-ROUNDDOWN([@[Start Time]],0)` here, allows you to enter a time with or without a date. It is not needed if your times do not also have a date attached.

[image]

### Using a lookup table instead

The benefit of using a lookup table is that you can easily see and change the cut off times in a single place, rather than searching through multiple formulas.

For Lookups, you should *NEVER* use `VLOOKUP`. `INDEX`/`MATCH` is better in every way. It is more efficient, less fragile, more versatile, and arguably easier to use, once you are familiar with it.

[image]

```
=INDEX(RefTbl[Times Of Day],MATCH([@[Start Time]]-ROUNDDOWN([@[Start Time]],0),RefTbl[End Time],-1))
```

Comment: XLOOKUP() is also a candidate to replace using index() with match()... just one function needed.

Comment: @SolarMike it is... if your Excel is new enough. I generally create workbooks to be used by a people with a variety of versions, so I tend to make use as universal formulas as I can.

Answer (score 1):

So, using vlookup() as suggested:

```
VLOOKUP(E2,$B$4:$C$8,2,1)
```

[image]

The advantage I find is that the times and the text are easily edited.

Comment: That works thankyou, But initially the data was in (dd:mm:yyyy hh:mm:ss) format, is there a way to use vlookup() directly to that?

Comment: Well, you accepted the other answer so the answer is yes you can expand to the format you suggest. I will let you have a go.

Answer (score 0):

Recent Excel version has two functions you might use for this: [`switch()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-function-47ab33c0-28ce-4530-8a45-d532ec4aa25e) handles the multiple `IF()` and [`LET()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999#:%7E:text=The%20LET%20function%20assigns%20names,through%20Excel%27s%20native%20formula%20syntax.) gives you the opportunity to create a temporary variable inside your formula. (I would have put this in a comment, but two large URLs make this comment too large)